# How to undo an iptables command?

Tags: iptables

I accidently did this iptables command on CentOS7. How to undo it?

```
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i src_if -o dst_if -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these:

- Reload all of your iptables rules using whichever method was used to load them during boot
- Run the same command but replace `-I` with `-D` to delete the matching rule
- Use `iptables -L --line-numbers` to list all your rules, and find the offending rule, and delete it with `iptables -D chain num` where chain is the name of the table (first word in the heading for the section) and num is the number on the left of the rule